# How can I perform left join of two tables when they are being updated

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables: tb1 and tb2, I'm performing left join to create new table called tb3,  from these two tables. once in a while, tb1 and tb2 are being updated with new rows and want to perform same left join to create updated tb3 table, can I do this task without writing new left joins everytime tables are updating? whats the best solution for that kind of task?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use a view:

```
create view v_tb3 as 
    select . . .
    from table1 t1 left join
         table2 t2
         on . . .
    . . .;
```

This will run the query every time you access the view.  That will ensure that the data is up-to-date.

If you actually want to persist the data as a table (so it does not need to be recalculated), then you can use a [*materialized view*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html):

```
create materialized view mv_tb3 as 
    select . . .
    from table1 t1 left join
         table2 t2
         on . . .
    . . .;
```

However, there are caveats on how recent the data is.  And maintaining the view requires overhead.  A `left join` is not typically particularly expensive, so I would generally recommend a simple view.